# Oracle APEX; changing location of apex_application.g_print_success_message

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I am using apex_application.g_print_success_message to display messages to the user and it always pops up in the upper right corner. Is it possible to relocate the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Check out the page template, it has a subtemplate named "Success Message". That section has all the classes that identify how the success message is rendered and where it is located on the page.
Now... what exactly you have to do to display it somewhere else, I can 't help you with that - that is a question for css wizards. It is definitely possible, I have worked on customized templates where the success message was located in another position - but in that project the UI was developed by a different team.

Comment: Glad to be of help - hope you can make it work for your requirement